# Replace keywords by images in TextField

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2

I have some textfield with text like "Click @button1, then @button2". Have you got any idea how to replace keywords by images ? I must do it in AS2 :/ I know there is htmlText in textField, but useing it I can only use one image, and image can only align left or right site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very advanced stuff. I can tell you there is no 'out of the box' solution like using html text fields or something similar. Especially if you want to mimic nearly html behaviour you have to code advanced routines that can : 1. recognize your keywords. You should google for tokenizers and 2. layout textfields according to occuring images and textblocks. Again, thats advanced!

Comment: I make it :) so question can be close. But I can't paste source, beacouse it isn't my.